# SQL implement complex data validation?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field which will contain a number, how can I do complex validation on that number on insertion?

I've got the validation algorithm implemented in java, just wondering how to "translate it" to SQL. Like I do some calculations with the inserted number and if the calculations don't match a predetermined result I want to reject that entry. How do I go about this?

I'm assuming I need to use a Check Constraint on the field, but how do I incorporate my validation algorithm in the constraint?

My algorithm looks like this

```
int s=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       s+=n%10;
       n/=10;
    }
if(n==s)
    //Good Value
```

Where `n` is initially my value to be inserted.

Comment: Please describe the logic you want, in words, and provide sample data and desired results. Not all SQL folks speak Java fluently.

Comment: Look for triggers ("insert trigger" in your case)

Comment: @GMB The validation algorithm is irrelevant. I'm wondering how to use an algorithm in a constraint (If that's where I should insert it). Any example (which can't be solved with a simple equation or comparison) would suffice.

Comment: by good value you means if the inserted value lies between say 1 to 10,not null, not negetive etc, it can be done in check constraint,

Comment: You can use a udf in a check constraint here

Comment: @Paul: *how to use an algorithm in a constraint*: I guess it would depend what kind of algorithm, hence my initial comment.

Comment: @Paul . . . For basically all real world data, ` check` constraints with regular expressions for strings and arithmetic operations are sufficient.  If you want your own special function, you can use a user defined function, but that is almost never necessary.  I also cannot think of any non-single digit numbers that meet your requirement, so `check (n between 0 and 9)` seems sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this check is complex you need to translate it in PL/SQL and add this logic in a BEFORE INSERT and/or a BEFORE UPDATE trigger.

Let's say you table is called `MY_TABLE` and contain a field  `MY_FIELD` which as a NUMBER datatype :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  TRIGGER_VALIDATE_N
BEFORE  
insert or update on MY_TABLE
for each row  
    s NUMBER := 0;
    n NUMBER;
begin  

    n := :OLD.MY_FIELD;

    FOR i IN 0..10 LOOP
        s := MOD(n,10);
        n := n/10;
    END LOOP;

    IF n = s THEN
        --Good Value
        null;
    ELSE
        --Wrong Value raise an error
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, TO_CHAR(:OLD.MY_FIELD)||' is a wrong value for MY_TABLE.MY_FIELD.');
    END IF;
end;  
/
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thank you for replying though, really appreciate it !